# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' googletrans python

Tags: python, python-3.x, googletrans

Windows 7

Python 3.8.2

googletrans 3.0.0

```
from googletrans import Translator

text = 'hello'
translator = Translator()
result = translator.translate(text).src
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\AB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\
googletrans\client.py", line 182, in translate
    data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\
googletrans\client.py", line 78, in _translate
    token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
  File "C:\Users\AB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\
googletrans\gtoken.py", line 194, in do
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\AB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\
googletrans\gtoken.py", line 62, in _update
    code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Before everything worked fine, a little later those errors began to appear, and now this error comes out after each function call.

Answer (score 8):

Try google_trans_new.
https://github.com/lushan88a/google_trans_new

```
pip install google_trans_new
```

```
from google_trans_new import google_translator
translator = google_translator()  
translate_text = translator.translate('Hello!',lang_src='en', lang_tgt='de')  
print(translate_text)
```

-> `Hallo!`

Comment: Unfortunately couldn't find a way to return confidence, unlike `from googletrans import Translator` followed by `translator.detect(YOUR_TEXT)` returns `<Detected lang=DETECTED_LANGUAGE confidence=SOME_CONFIDENCE>`

Answer (score 1):

you have to increase the googletrans version from version 3.0.0 to version 4.0.0 by typing pip install googletrans==4.0.0-rc1

Comment: Can you please provide more information on how this solves the problem? Thanks!